# Add new attributes on element HTML in KB cognitive Services

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I want to set new attributes on element html (`a` or `b`) in answers intent.
[image]

I tried to paste the element `<a href="#" onclick="try{console.log("test");}catch(i){}>Operatore</a>` and the  portal remove always the attribute `onclick`. I tried also `<a href="#" onclick:try{console.log("test");}catch(i){} >Operatore</a>` with result negative.

There is a way for set attribute on elements html?

Answer (score 0):

Direct adding option is not yet fully functional. Instead, follow the alternative relative approach.

Use [Curl](https://curl.se/) tool for this operation.

1. From the settings tab of knowledge base, select the **CURL** tab.
2. Copy the command to the editable environment.

Follow the steps mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/quickstarts/get-answer-from-knowledge-base-using-url-tool?pivots=url-test-tool-curl).